# mysql error: can't destroy an object that is created using factoryGirl

Tags: mysql, rspec, connection, destroy, initialization

I was using mysql db to run rspec in rails. After I create an object using factoryGirl, I would like to destroy it so that the db looks clean for the next spec running.
Here is how i set up in my spec:

```
before (:each) do
  User.destroy_all
  @user = Factory.create :user
end

after (:each) do
 @user.destroy
end
```

I got an error running rspec:

```
Failure/Error: @user.destroy_all
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::connection

Failure/Error: @user.destroy
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User::connection
```

I do set up `:dependent => :destroy` in user model
What is wrong here?

Comment: be careful... and not to say factoryWife! That would be even harder to destroy! So be careful before upgrading .... :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the Object referenced with the @user class variable is an "Uninitialized Constant". IE, FactoryGirl is working fine, your variables are not correctly instantiating the @user object. You probably have an reference to connection when connection is not a datbase table field.

If it was a MySQL issue, there would be error messages associated with ActiveRecord.

If you want to clean your database before/after tests, try using this gem. It works great.
http://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner

Here's how I configured with RSpec in [a rails project](https://github.com/westonplatter/questionnaire_engine/blob/f96b2ab4edf5837fb7c272f4dcec855811cab97a/spec/spec_helper.rb),

```
RSpec.configure do |config|        
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end
  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```